# Open XLS File in a new window

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have simple Question and I would love to if someone can show me how to do it correctly,

I have a function that retrieving data

From the DB and I want to by click on button to export all the data to excel File

the thing is the file been saved on my C:\ drive and I want to open the file in a new window

or making saveFileDialog how can I do this?

---

```
Private Sub DatatableToExcel(ByVal dtTemp As DataTable)
        Dim _excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        wBook = _excel.Workbooks.Add()
        wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()


        Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = dtTemp
        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            _excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
        Next

        For Each dr In dt.Rows
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            colIndex = 0
            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                _excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
            Next
        Next

        wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
        Dim strFileName As String = "C:\Testing.xlsx"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
        End If

        wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)
        wBook.Close()
        _excel.Quit()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Not C#. Removing tag. Please don't add irrelevant tags for visibility.

Comment: yeah sorry I'm kinda new here

Answer (score 0):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with you're Excel file name as parameter.

Comment: can you show me how to open it in a new window? or maybe using FileSaveDialog for the user?

Comment: Process.Start launches Excel and opens your file in a new window. FileSaveDialog just asks the user where to save the file.

Comment: I tried that its not working. Process.Start there is any way that you can show me how to use FileSaveDialog on my code?

Comment: it needs to be simple like open in a new window or something your code Process.Strat is not working.